# How to count the changes done in new csv file compared to the previous

Tags: python, csv

We have two csv files - `new.csv` and `old.csv`.

`old.csv` contains with four rows:

```
    abc done
    xyz done
    pqr done
    rst pending
```

The `new.csv` contains four new rows:

```
    abc pending
    xyz not_done
    pqr pending
    rst done
```

I need to use count two things without using pandas

- count1 = number of entries changed from done to pending = 2 (abc, pqr)
- count2 = number of entries changed from done to not_done = 1 (xyz)

Comment: the numbers "three" and "five" don't match the csv you show

Comment: If both csv always have the same amount and order of items you could iterate using `zip` and filter for lines which are not equal. Something along the lines of `sum([1 for a,b in zip(csv1.readlines(), csv2.readlines()) if a != b])`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom check it now

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1: CSV Files are in the same order**

Firstly import the two files into python lists:

```py
oldcsv = []
with open("old.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        oldcsv.append(line.strip().split(","))
newcsv = []
with open("new.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        newcsv.append(line.strip().split(","))
```

Now you would simply iterate through both lists simultaneously, using zip(). I am assuming that both CSV files list the entries in the same order.

```py
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
for oldentry, newentry in zip(oldcsv, newcsv):
    assert(oldentry[0] == newentry[0]) # Throw error if entry names do not match
    if oldentry[1] == "done":
        if newentry[1] == "pending":
            count1 += 1
        elif newentry[1] == "not_done":
            count2 += 1
```

**CASE 2: CSV Files are in arbitrary order**

Here, given you are going to be needing to look up entries by their names, I would use a dictionary rather than a list to store the old.csv data, mapping the entry names to their values:

```py
# Load old.csv data into a dictionary mapping entry_name: entry_value
old_values = {}
with open("old.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        old_entry = line.strip().split(",")
        entry_name, old_entry_value = old_entry[0], old_entry[1] 
        old_values[entry_name] = old_entry_value

count1 = 0
count2 = 0

with open("new.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        # For each entry in new_entry, look up the corresponding old entry in old_entries, and compare their values.
        new_entry = line.strip().split(",")
        entry_name, new_entry_value = new_entry[0], new_entry[1]
        old_entry_value = old_values.get(entry_name) # Get the old value for this entry (will be None if there is no old entry)
        # Essentially same code as before:
        print(f"{entry_name}: old entry status is {old_entry_value} and new entry status is {new_entry_value}")
        if old_entry_value == "done":
            if new_entry_value == "pending":
                print("Incrementing count1")
                count1 += 1
            elif new_entry_value == "not_done":
                print("Incrementing count2")
                count2 += 1
print(count1)
print(count2)
```

This should work, as long as the input data is properly formatted. I am assuming each .csv file has one entry per line, and each line begins with the entry name (e.g. "abc"), then a comma, then the entry value (e.g. "done","not_done").

Comment: Got Assertion Error ,also the order may not remain same.Can you help me

Comment: I've updated the answer now, for the case in which the entries could be in any order.

Comment: Getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)  at line "entry_name, old_entry_value = line.strip().split(",")"

Comment: What is the structure of the .csv file? I had initially assumed that there were only two values per line, so each line looked like "abc,done" with no extra values. I've modified the code now so that it can handle there being extra values after the first two in the .csv files (by ignoring them).

Comment: In your code count is even increasing if new row is being add ed with pending or not_done status which was not there in old csv.

Comment: What do you mean by a status which was not there in the old csv? Are there some entries names which aren't in old.csv but are being introduced in new.csv? In that case the code would need slightly rewritten

Comment: Yes exactly you got it right , In new.csv we are adding new entries which are also getting added to the count1 & count2

Comment: I think there is a mismatch lets take a example;in old.csv I have entry [abc,done] and in new.csv I have[abc,pending] and[pqr,pending] I just want count=1 as abc status has changed and pqr is the new entry it should not effect the count,Count should only be effected if status has changed not if new entry is added

Comment: Ok, so you can use old_values.get(entry_name) instead of old_values[entry_name] (I've updated the answer) so that the code can handle not being able to find an old entry with the corresponding name. The behaviour I think you've asked for, and what the code I've written should do is as follows: for each new entry, if it's status is "done" but the corresponding old entry's status is "pending", count1 is incremented. If the new entry's status is "done" &the corresponding old entry's status is "not_done", count2 is incremented. If the corresponding old entry does not exist, nothing is incremented.

Comment: You gave correct explanation but i still see the increment.

Comment: I just tried testing the code above with the example you gave (in old.csv I have entry [abc,done] and in new.csv I have[abc,pending] and[pqr,pending]), and it seemed to give the correct answer, count1=1. Are there cases in which it's giving the wrong answer?

Comment: You are hitting right but I am not able to get the correct so I am taking old.csv as[a,done][b,done][c,done][d,done][e,done][f,done][g,done][h,done][i,done][j,done]
and new.csv [a,Pending][b,Pending][c,Pending][d,Pending][e,Pending][f,not_done][g,not_done][h,not_done][i,not_done][j,not_done][k,not_done][l,not_done][m,pending]
so count1=6 and count2=7 is coming for me

Comment: Really sorry, I've not been able to replicate that - I've created an old.csv file and a new.csv file with the data in it you just listed, and have tested the code on it, and I get count1=5 and count2=5 (which I believe is what it should be giving). I've added some print statements to the code, which when you execute it might help you work out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure python straightforward implementation:

```py
import csv

with open("old.csv") as old_fl:
    with open("new.csv") as new_fl:
        old = csv.reader(old_fl)
        new = csv.reader(new_fl)
        
        old_rows = [row for row in old]
        new_rows = [row for row in new]

        # see if this is really needed
        assert len(old_rows) == len(new_rows)
        n = len(old_rows)

        # assume that left key is identical,
        # and in the same order in both files
        assert all(old_rows[i][0] == new_rows[i][0] for i in range(n))

        # once the data is guaranteed to align,
        # just count what you want
        done_to_pending = [
            f"row[{i}]( {old_rows[i][0]} )"
            for i in range(n)
            if old_rows[i][1] == "done" and new_rows[i][1] == "pending"
        ]

        done_to_notdone = [
            f"row[{i}]( {old_rows[i][0]} )"
            for i in range(n)
            if old_rows[i][1] == "done" and new_rows[i][1] == "not_done"
        ]
```

It uses the python native csv reader so you don't need to parse the csv yourself. Note that there are various assumptions (`assert` statements) throughout the code - you might need to adjust the code to handle more cases.